# Question regarding double angle formula? Trig

Tags: trigonometry

A question on my homework asks to find $\tan (2B)$ if $\tan B=-\frac{12}{5}$ and $ B\in (\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$. I was told that to find the quadrant your answer is in, you multiply by $2$, but that would make it quadrantal? How do you determine as to whether or not your answer is going to be positive or negative? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tan is sine by cosine. It is negative in the second and fourth quadrant, and is positive in the first and third quadrant. If you know how to find $\tan 2B$ (direct from formula) $= \frac{2 \tan B}{1 - \tan^2 B}$ then the sign of the tangent will tell you what quadrant the angle is in.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the point $P=(-5,12)$ which corresponds to the angle with measure $B$. Since $|12| > |-5|$, we can say that $90^\circ < B < 135^\circ$ (the point P is above the line y=-x). It follows that  $180^\circ < 2B < 270^\circ$, which puts the angle with measure $2B$ in the third quadrant. So $\tan 2B$ will be positive.

Answer (score 0):

$B \in (\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)\implies2B \in (\pi,2\pi)$

Also, $\tan B < -1 \implies B < \frac{3\pi}{4}$

So, $2B <\frac{3\pi}{2}$

Hence, $2B\in (\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2})$ and so $\tan 2B > 0$.